# OpenCV Slow camera framerate

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I just copied an program to detect faces through webcam but the video capture is really slow, and i dont know how to fix it!

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
#include<opencv2\objdetect\objdetect.hpp>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include<vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
if(!face_cascade.load("c:\\haar\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")) {
    printf("Error loading cascade file for the face");
    return 1;
}
VideoCapture capture(0);
if(!capture.isOpened())
{
    printf("Error trying to start the Camera");
    return 1;
}
Mat cap_img,gray_img;
vector<Rect> faces;
while(1)
{
    capture >> cap_img;
    waitKey(10);
    cvtColor(cap_img, gray_img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::equalizeHist(gray_img,gray_img);
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, faces, 1.1, 10, CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE | CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(0,0), cvSize(300,300));
    for(int i=0; i < faces.size();i++)
    {
        Point pt1(faces[i].x+faces[i].width, faces[i].y+faces[i].height);
        Point pt2(faces[i].x,faces[i].y);
        rectangle(cap_img, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(191,191,191), 2, 8, 0);
    }
    imshow("Result", cap_img);
    waitKey(3);
    char c = waitKey(3);
    if(c == 27)
        break;
}
return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual studio 2012 and this is the main.cpp file. Im using OpenCV 2.4.9!

Comment: Did you compile in debug or in release mode? OpenCv's runtime is greatly improved when compiled and run in release mode!

Comment: In release mode it is giving me an exe missing error! It's the first time im working with OpenCv..

Comment: Looks like the Libraries paths get messed up when i change it to release mode, i dont know why! Here is a print screen of some of the errors when i change it to release mode...
http://i.imgur.com/9aXf9GA.png

Comment: You will have to setup your project properties the same way as you did in debug mode. Otherwise, neither your header files nor the libs can be found. IMPORTANT: Make sure you specify the libraries whose filenames are not suffixed with a 'd'. E.g. `opencv_imgproc249.lib` instead of `opencv_imgproc249d.lib`

Comment: Ok, thanks man. There are no errors now but still the Exe missing error!

Comment: It's working now, i just had to change some stuff in the preprocessor to accept fopen! Thanks for everything man, it is working now :)

Comment: The Framerate is a lot better now, but do u know something more to increase it?

Comment: You should definitely get rid of all those `waitKey()` calls. It waits the given amount of time in milliseconds. Just keep the last three lines of your while loop and remove the other two calls.

Comment: Wow thanks man, its really faster now! You're a OpenCV professional xd

Comment: I'll post a summary as an answer then. Please accept it by ticking the green check mark next to that answer to mark that it solved your problem.

Comment: Yes man, of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV comes with prebuild libraries. When you use them in an application you actually want to deploy make sure you use the release libraries. In debug mode you have lots of additional checks in the form of `asserts` as well as debug symbols allowing you to step into the libraries with a debugger that are removed in release mode.

Another more specific advise regarding the code you posted: Avoid calls to `cv::waitKey()` as every single call, who would have guessed, makes your main thread wait the specified amount of time in milliseconds. Do not drop calls to it entirely as e.g. `cv::imshow()` will only work appropriately with these in place.

---

**Edit:**

Reduce your while loop to:

```
while ( true ) {
    capture >> cap_img;
    imshow("Result", cap_img);

    if(waitKey(1) == 27)
        break;
}
```

When you know how much time you need for capturing the image and just displaying it, then you can compare how much of an impact whatever algorithm you are running has on your performance.

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help you out ;)

Comment: Just one fast question, OpenCV is normaly slow with webcams? because It is a lot faster now but still 1 sec delay or something.

Comment: If you want to check the impact of your tracking code on the runtime just comment everything but the first and the last 5 lines of the code you posted and set the argument of `cv::waitKey(x)` to x = 1. That will be as fast as you can get with your current hardware.

Comment: Which lines? can u tell me which lines should i not comment?

Comment: By the way, im working for school, one guy here said that it should be geting like +30fps and talked about changing the format to mpeg-4 or something like that, do you know something about this?

Comment: I'm definitely no expert myself. But since you're just reading from your webcam stream you should not be able to change the format of any kind as you would be when using a video as input. For now, please measure your fps and also list your current hardware setup. Otherwise I can't tell you if what you perceive as 'slow' is actually slow, or not. So, please read up a bit about profiling your current code and report back with your measurements.

Comment: Somehow now is giving me this error: http://i.imgur.com/MkcpX1Y.png
I dont know what this is, even trying to run other projects its giving me this error! I tried to create another project with same code and still, wtf!

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution...everytime you read!!!..everytime you use vcap>>cap or cap.read(vcap)... you must set FPS ..25 is max..if i try to set 26 or higher it runs slow.
...this runs 30 fps for me
If you not set FPS...it runs slow too

```
if (cap.read(vcap)){
        imshow("Cam Feed", vcap);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 25);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of the other answers, Multiprocessing is what fixed my issue. I split my program into 3 processes. One for grabbing the image, one for processing the image, and one for displaying the image. Referencing [this page](https://www.programmersought.com/article/10121175018/) helped me a lot. I also followed the tips of the other answers here.